# google chart multiple values in one column

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

How make a possible to display 2 values in 1 column (split red and yellow columns in one)?
I have plan of sold  and value of sold ordered by months.
For ex:
Jan -
plan:100, sold:80
Feb -
plan:150, sold:150
So i want to see 2(4 columns in mind, second value should overlap first value)    columns:
100 80
150  150
first column will be colored in two colors because sold value less then plan   (100/80 )
second column will be colored in one color(yellow), because second column overlap first value 150/150
`isStacked: true` doesn't overlay first column

Thanks for advise.

Code that i use [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swpwoffb/1/) and [what I need](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16738968/googleChart.png)

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

        function drawStacked() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Plan');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Sold');
            data.addRows([
                ['Jan, 2015', 100, 80],
                ['Feb, 2015', 150, 150],
            ]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {
                colors: ['red', 'yellow'],
                width: 600,
                height: 175,
                title: 'Total',
                legend: 'none',
            });

        }
```

Comment: Use a diff chart and set inner bar width to outer bar width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just doing a pie sample so I set up a diff bar sample with your data. It has our PDF print code in it but shows what I think you want (except the color):

http://jsfiddle.net/1og99wL1/

```
function drawChart() {
        var oldData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        oldData.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        oldData.addColumn('number', 'Plan');
        oldData.addRows([
            ['Jan, 2015', 100],
            ['Feb, 2015', 150],
        ]);
        var newData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        newData.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        newData.addColumn('number', 'Sold');
        newData.addRows([
            ['Jan, 2015', 80],
            ['Feb, 2015', 150],
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        var data = chart.computeDiff(oldData, newData);
        var options = {
            colors: ['yellow'],
            diff: { 
                 oldData: { opacity: 1, color: '#ff0000' }, 
                 newData: { opacity: 1, widthFactor: 1 }
            },
            legend: 'none',
            width: 600
        };
        <!-- For the PDF print -->
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', AddNamespace);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comments:

You must use "oldData" and "newData" as the names for the datasets. You cannot just choose arbitrary names. If you do, the chart will draw but the "diff" option will not work (crazy, must be burned into the code). The color must be set like below with one color set in "colors" option and the other set in "diff" option.

Comment: Awesome! That is what I need. Thank You Kevin !

Comment: I need to change tooltip text which is currently showing in hover, Current and Previous.  Is there any way to change that **Current** and **Previous** with different custom text?

Comment: Please post a question and not extend the one asked. You can refer to it but you have a different question.